# Задание не проходит, просьба пояснить, почему

Tags: java

Напишите класс Vector2D (вектор на плоскости).

В классе необходимо предусмотреть:

Два публичных дробных поля (double) vX и vY - значения проекций вектора на оси.

Конструктор без параметров, который инициализирует вектор значениями (1,1).

Конструктор с двумя параметрами (проекция на ось X, проекция на ось Y).

Конструктор с параметром Vector2D (такие конструкторы в литературе принято называть конструкторами копирования).

Метод print(), который выводит вектор на экран в виде: (vX, vY), при этом значения проекций округлить до двух знаков после запятой. Разделитель в дробных числах - точка. Например, при печати вектора с проекциями vX = 1.2374 и vY = 2.2334, на экране должно появиться (1.24, 2.23).

Для организации форматного вывода можно воспользоваться методом format класса String. После выполнения следующей строки

System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", 1.2345));
на экране появится число 1.23.

В ответе нужно указать только описание класса.

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Vector2D {
    double vX;
    double vY;

    public Vector2D() {
        vX = 1;
        vY = 1;
    }

    public Vector2D(double vX, double vY) {

    }

    public Vector2D(double Vector2D) {

    }

    public static void print(double vX, double vY) {
        System.out.println("( " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", vX)) + ", " + (String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", vY)) + ")");
    }
}
```

---

Итого

import java.util.Locale;

```
public class Vector2D {
    double vX;
    double vY;

    public Vector2D() {
        vX = 1;
        vY = 1;
    }

    public Vector2D(double vX, double vY) {
        this.vX = vX;
        this.vY = vY;
    }

    public Vector2D(Vector2D other) {
        vX = other.vX;
        vY = other.vY;
    }

    public static void print(double vX, double vY) {
        System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "(%.2f, %.2f)", vX, vY));
    }
}
```

Однако все равно не проходит :(

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать *желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения* **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

```
public Vector2D(double vX, double vY) {

}
```

Тут вы конструктор сделали, но ничего в нем не делаете. Параметры же не используются нигде. Сереньким подсвечиваются из-за этого. инициализацию добавить надо все же

```
public Vector2D(double vX, double vY) {
    this.vX = vX;
    this.vY = vY;    
}
```

> Конструктор с параметром Vector2D (такие конструкторы в литературе
>   принято называть конструкторами копирования).

Когда говорят про этот конструктор - имеют в виду что вы создаете новый вектор, в параметрах указав уже существующий. И новый вектор должен быть копией переданного в параметр. А вы тут создали конструктор, который принимает в параметрах одно дробное число. Должно быть так

```
public Vector2D(Vector2D other) {
    vX = other.vX;
    vY = other.vY;
}
```

Ну и, напоследок, вывод вот так лучше сделать:

```
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "(%.2f, %.2f)", vX, vY));
```

Comment: Дмитрий, указал ниже

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Vector2D {
    public double vX;
    public double vY;

    public Vector2D() {
        this.vX = 1;
        this.vY = 1;
    }

    public Vector2D(double vX, double vY) {
        this.vX = vX;
        this.vY = vY;
    }

    public Vector2D(Vector2D v) {
        this.vX = v.vX;
        this.vY = v.vY;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.printf("(%.2f, %.2f)\n", this.vX, this.vY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector2D v = new Vector2D(1.2374, 2.2334);
        Vector2D v2 = new Vector2D();
        Vector2D v3 = new Vector2D(v);
        v.print();
        v2.print();
        v3.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]